# react setSelectedGame is not a function

Tags: reactjs

**App.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Game from './components/Game'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [selectedGame, setSelectedGame] = useState('/')

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <div className='container'>
        <Router>
          <Switch>

            <Route exact path='/' setSelectedGame={setSelectedGame}> // <----------------
              <Home />
            </Route>

            <Route path={`/games/${selectedGame}`}>
              <Game />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = ({setSelectedGame}) => {
    const [previews, setPreviews] = useState([])
    const [images, setImages] = useState('')

    const history = useHistory()

    const redirectGame = title => {
        setSelectedGame(title) // <-----------------
        history.push(`/games/${title}`)
    }

    return (
        <div class="container">
        <section class="games">

        {previews.map(preview => (
                <div class="game">
                <div class="game-content">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <div class="image-container" onClick={() => redirectGame(preview.title)}>
                            <img 
                            src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/previews/thumbnail/${preview.id}`} className='cover'
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ))}

        </section>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

What I'm trying to do is when a user clicks on the image container it will take the title and send it to its parent component which is App.js which will be stored in the selectedGame state via the redirectGame() function which is located in Home.js,this was working completely fine until now.. how can I fix this.

Comment: What problem are you facing right now?

Comment: I am not able to send the title that is located in Home.js to the parent component App.js

Comment: just a string, lets say the games title is Tetris, when the user clicks on it I need the 'Tetris' value to be sent to App.js

Comment: You need to pass `setSelectedGame` to your `Home` component, not `Route`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Route exact path='/' >
   <Home setSelectedGame={setSelectedGame}  />
</Route>
```